# SOQL: Accessing Contact Email Addresses through Junction Object

Tags: soql, contact

I have the following many-to-many relationship, linking "Contact" and "Distribution_List__c" with the "Distribution_List_Junction__c" object:

```
Contact - Distribution_List_Junction__c - Distribution_List__c
```

Given a particular Distribution List name, I am trying to retrieve the email addresses of its member Contacts.  So far I have the following, which seems to retrieve Contact IDs as child records:

```
SELECT (select Contact__c from Distribution_List_Junctions__r ) FROM Distribution_List__c WHERE Name = 'Distribution List 1'
```

However, I'm not sure where to go from here.  I assume that I will have to then query the Contacts object based on those Contact IDs, but I can't tell how to do that efficiently.  Is it even necessary to do the separate query?

I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as stated above that's how you would form the query, then to access the data you would do something like this:

```
for (Distribution_List__c dl : [SELECT (SELECT Contact__c, Contact__r.Email FROM Distribution_List_Junctions__r ) FROM Distribution_List__c WHERE Name = 'Distribution List 1') {
  if (dl.Distribution_List_Junctions__r != null && !dl.Distribution_List_Junctions__r.isEmpty()) {
    // access it by for loop or by dl.Distribution_List_Junctions__r[0].Contact__r.Email
    for (Distribution_List_Junctions__c dlj : dl.Distribution_List_Junctions__r) {
      //do something with dlj.Contact__r.Email
    }
  }
}
```

I know I had issues at first figuring out how to access the data, and there are still a few more ways you can do it, it just depends on what you need to do with it :-)

Comment: Junctions will always be != null so that 1 check can be skipped. They might be an empty list but still - something will be there. And we don't have "above" here, nobody says your answer won't be upvoted over mine eventually, it is more helpful after all ;)

Comment: :-) i tend to over check for null sometimes :-P

Comment: Thank you SalesForceGirl!  This was the part I was missing.  You're a star.

Comment: no problem :-) its the part i was first stuck on lol, let me know if you need anything else, or how you are trying to use the data

Answer (score 6):

Go "up" on Contact:

```
SELECT 
    (select Contact__c, Contact__r.Email from Distribution_List_Junctions__r ) 
FROM Distribution_List__c 
WHERE Name = 'Distribution List 1'
```

Comment: Thank you eyescream - together your and SalesForceGirl's answers solved my problem!